# Free heap memory

Tags: ram, gcc, programming, c, memory-leak

So I'm using Ubuntu for programming I use atom text editor with gcc compiler for C. I want to ask what will happen if I don't clear memory allocated by malloc or calloc? Will the OS take care of it or I have to clear it. In case I forgot.

Comment: This sounds more like a programming related question than an Ubuntu related one, because of memory allocation and such (that's typically not OS-specific...)

Comment: You will have to take care of freeing memory. Allocated memory will be freed automatically when the process stops though. But if you have a long running process leaking memory by not free'ing it can make your system run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you @Soren A by the way I'm just a beginner and learning the C language.

Comment: @Ojas, thats fine .. we all started there ;-) I will make my comment an answer, please accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take care of freeing memory your self. C doesn't have automatic memory management like JAVA and others.

Allocated memory will be freed automatically when the process stops though.

But if you have a long running process, leaking memory by not free'ing it, can make your system run out of memory.